# Sunspot Solr search using false value

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, search, solr, sunspot-solr

I want to implement a search for a solr filed when from view a checkbox is clicked

what parameter should I send?

My solr store is as follows

**boolean :from_vendor do
  !from_vendor?
end**

Where from_vendor is boolean attribute in the table, I want to exclude from_vendor => true from my search, so I must search by false value as a search param, so that the shebang(!) sign can be avoided in the store.

Not sure what should I send as the search param, because the logic is, splitting up the param string , and based upon that assign condition to it, like, if I send params as

**"0,+"** , it means solr will search for all with value greater than 0. now In my case how should I construct my params?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us the code that you tried and give us an idea of why the results weren't satisfactory?

Comment: from where I am building the search params I am doing like this

search_params[:s][:from_vendor] = "0" if params[:q][:exclude_vendor] == "1"

The exclude vendor param is coming from the view checkbox, when it is checked, I am supposed to send a false somehow to solr, so that

Comment: "0" comes in the solr search params, Now it is taking it as a true, tried with different alternatives like "1", "false", "true" also, all are going as true to solr search. I cannot write true/false straight away because I am supposed to send a string parameter. Can you help me to construct the params so that I will be able to send a false value to solr and thus remove the shebang from the store I mentioned??Thanks in advance!

Comment: For your reference you can check the following file in spree_sunspot_solr gem

https://github.com/jbrien/spree_sunspot_search/blob/master/lib/spree/sunspot/filter/condition.rb

Comment: Hi - comment code-formatting is awful. Can you please edit your question and add the code there (it is part of your question). thanks :)